# An interesting integral about γ

Tags: calculus, integration, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant, fractional-part

It is well known that

$$\gamma = \lim_{n \to +\infty} (H_n − \ln(n)) = 0.5772(...)$$

where $H_n$ is the sum of reciprocals of all integers from $1$ to $n$.

Prove that  $$\int_1^\infty \frac{\{ x\}}{x^2} dx = 1 - \gamma$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\{x\} = x - \lfloor  x \rfloor$, then:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{\{x\}}{x^2} \ \text{d}x & = \int_1^{+\infty} \left(x - \lfloor  x \rfloor \right) \dfrac{\text{d}x}{x^2} \\\\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_1^n \left(x - \lfloor  x \rfloor\right) \dfrac{\text{d}x}{x^2} \\\\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \ln(n) - \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \int_k^{k+1} \dfrac{k}{x^2}\ \text{d}x \\\\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \ln(n) - \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} k \left(\dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k+1}\right) \\\\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \ln(n) - \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{k+1} \\\\
& = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \ln(n) - H_n + 1 \\\\
& = 1 - \gamma
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Where $H_n$ is the $n-$th Harmonic number.